# How to remove duplication of code in styled components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd, styled-components

Currently, I am using **antd** and **styled components** in my project.

However, while using **antd** as a component of **styled components**, the following code was repeated.

```
import { DownOutlined, VerticalLeftOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import styled from "styled-components";

const Button = styled(DownOutlined)`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;  
`;

const AnotherButton = styled(VerticalLeftOutlined)`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
`;
```

I want to remove code duplication of **AnotherButton** variable by dynamically changing only () part of **Button** variable.

```
import { DownOutlined, VerticalLeftOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import styled from "styled-components";

// How to dynamically apply DownOutlined, VerticalLeftOutlined inside ()
const Button = styled()`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;  
`;
```

Is there any way to solve the problem described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the *common* styles to a variable to make it reusable between components.

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const commonStyles = css`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;  
`;

const Button = styled(DownOutlined)`
  ${commonStyles};
`;

const AnotherButton = styled(VerticalLeftOutlined)`
  ${commonStyles};
`;
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I was able to resolve my questions.